# Creating a social site completely with Javascript

Tags: javascript, social-networking, javascript-framework

I'm working on a social network site. Some suggestions have been made to create the entire site in JavaScript and use JSON to interact with the database. So essentially each call to the server would return some js files that create the page on the client side.

I think a template framework on the server side would be a better idea - something like django.

I'm curious as to what the pros/ cons / roadblocks of a completely javascript solution where everything down to page layout is defined in javascript.

Comment: This is exactly how Facebook works. The keyword you are looking for is **"single page application"** (or SPA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major con of an all javascript site is how to enable search engines to see the content you want them to see.  Since most search engines don't run javascript, they don't see content you fetch and render in javascript.  If you don't need SEO, then you can ignore this con.

Another con is that an all javascript site may not be accessible to screen readers and other tools used by visually impaired folks.

It is more common these days to use a combination of web-served pages/content and then use javascript to enhance the experience and implement features and dynamic behaviors in the page.

Comment: @Raynos - I'm not sure what you mean by no caching.  You can get very efficient caching of the javascript code that runs the app.

Comment: I meant contend generated or rendered using javascript generally isn't cached. Where as HTTP requests for HTML are cached. You'd be hard pressed to find a templating engine that aggressively caches compiled templates based on input in say localStorage.

Comment: A follow up question...Does this approach (putting everything into Javascript - and having no html files and not much css) go against the philosophy of HTML5?